# Sequence of a dense set

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology

Let $\mathbb{X}$ be a metric space with metric function $d_{\mathbb{X}}(\cdot,\cdot):\mathbb{X}\to\mathbb{R}_+$. Suppose $Y\subseteq\mathbb{X}$ is a dense set. Let $\{y_1,y_2,y_3,...\}\subsetneq Y$ be a countable sequence. Is it true that this sequence is also dense in $\mathbb{X}$? If not under what conditions would it be true?

Comment: In general the statement is not true. Just take with the standard metric, $X=\mathbb{R}, Y=\mathbb{Q}$ and the countable subset as $\mathbb{Z}$.

Comment: @AnuragA, your comment should be an answer.

Comment: In general  a metric space, or any topological space, need not have a countable dense subset. For example let $\Bbb X=\Bbb R$ (or any other uncountable set) and let $d(a,b)=1$ whenever $a \ne b$  ( "the" discrete metric). Then the only dense subset of $\Bbb X$ is $\Bbb X$.